# sqlite3 trigger to auto-add new month record

Tags: triggers, sqlite

I need to automatically insert a row in a stats table that is identified by the month number, if the new month does not exist as a row.

'cards' is a running count of individual IDs that stores a current value (gets reset at rollover time), a rollover count and a running total of all events on that ID

'stats keeps a running count of all IDs events, and how many rollovers occurred in a given month.

```
CREATE TABLE IDS (ID_Num VARCHAR(30), Curr_Count INT, Rollover_Count INT, Total_Count INT);
CREATE TABLE stats(Month char(10), HitCount int, RolloverCount int);
CREATE TRIGGER update_Tstats BEFORE UPDATE OF Total_Count ON IDS
WHEN 0=(SELECT HitCount from stats WHERE Month = strftime('%m','now'))
```

(Also tried a "IS NULL" at the other end of the WHEN clause...still no joy)

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO stats (Month, HitCount, RolloverCount) VALUES (strftime('%m', 'now'),0,0);
END;
```

I did have it working to a point, but as rollover was updated twice per cycle (value changed up and down via SQL query I have in a python script), it gave me doubleups in the stats rollover count.  So now I'm running a double query in my script.  However, this all fall over if the current month number does not exist in the stats table.

All I need to do is check if a blank record exists for the current month for the python script UPDATE queries to run against, and if not, INSERT one.  The script itself can't do a 'run once' type of query on initial runup, because it may run for days, including spanning a new month changeover.

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether a record exists, use EXISTS:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stats WHERE Month = ...)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO stats ...
END;
```

Comment: You know how sometimes you are looking so hard at a problem and can't see the answer right in front of your face?  This is one of those times!  Exactly what I almost answered in my own question...Thanks CL for your quick response :-)